# CLLocationManager didUpdateToLocation is called after all views are loaded

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I want to get the current location using `CoreLocation` framework and i'm doing that inside the AppDelegate as much views in my app will need the result `longitude` and `latitude` the following method get the current location:

```
(void)loadCurrentLocation{
NSLog(@"loadCurrentLocation");
if (manager==nil) {
    manager=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
}

 manager.delegate=self;
 manager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
 [manager startUpdatingLocation];

}
```

Given that manager is declared in `AppDelegate.h` as follows:

```
CLLocationManager *manager;
```

I'm calling the above method inside AppDelegate's `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method,
the problem is that the `didUpdateToLocation` method which has much logic common for all the views is called after all the views is loaded !! i want this method to be called before any `viewDidLoad` method in order to do some logic based on `didUpdateToLocation`
Note: I tried to call this method inside `+(void)initialise` of the `AppDelegate.m` and the same problem occurs, what is the possible solution to that ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`startUpdatingLocation` is an asynchronous method [which may take several seconds](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startUpdatingLocation).

You should rather implement some logic to notify your views about (or make your view controllers listening to) current location changes and then update your UI properly.

Don't depend on asynchronous methods/callbacks in main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Post this notification on didUpdateLocations like this:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"LocationUpdate" object:locations];
}
```

Then register to the "LocationUpdate" notification on each view's viewDidLoad then handle it according to your programming logic.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(LocationUpdate:) name:@"LocationUpdate" object:nil];
}
-(void)LocationUpdate:(NSArray*)locations
{
//handle location update here
}
```